# debugging:: gdb :: what is src2dst?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

Have anyone an idea or a link to an explanation regarding src2dst in gdb? as in :

```
#8  __cxxabiv1::__dynamic_cast (src_ptr=0x5aa21d0, src_type=0x7f1e92dd5840, dst_type=0x7f1e8d2751a0, src2dst=0) at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/dyncast.cc:57
```

and related to this: what can be the cause of an dynamic cast that goes wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `dynamic_cast` across shared libraries with `dlopen`? There are special precautions to make it work. See this [GCC FAQ](http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#dso).

Answer (score 0):

`src2dst` seems to be a type in your case. I believe the crash you are reffering to is through the file, **[cxxabi.h](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/histar/src/lib/cppsup/cxxabi.h)**, You can find the details of what `src2dst` refers to in this particular file.